# XBAP project with multiple pages

Tags: xbap

I have one `XBAP(abc.windowloading)` project in my application with `Page1.xaml, Page2.xmal etc...`
When I am trying to deploy it's `creating abc.windowloading.XBAP` file and all other required file in the deployment directory and I am hosting it into `Iframes`,
But my requirement is to load first page(`Page1.xaml`) into first `IFrame` and second `page(Page2.xaml)` into second `IFrame` , how I can do this task?

```
iframe src='abc.windowloading.xbap\Page1.xaml' width='1024' height='1024'

iframe src='abc.windowloading.xbap\Page2.xaml' width='1024' height='1024'
```

It's not working in that way